# solving for a particular solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I find a particular solution to this given ODE:

$$t^2y^{''} - 4ty^{'} + 6y =t^{\frac{7}{2}}$$

I already have the complementary equation where I used the method of reduction but I just don't know how to solve for the particular solution. Can someone guide me through it?.

Comment: Can you show us your complementary equation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**: Considering the RHS of the ODE the solution will be of the form $y = at^b$ where $a,b$ are constants you solve for using the ODE, that would give you a solution.

$$
y(t) = at^b\\
y(t)' = ab{t}^{b-1}\\
y(t)'' = ab(b-1){t}^{b-2}\\
$$

Substituting in the ODE we get:

$$
t^2y''-4ty'+6y = {t}^{\frac{7}{2}}\\
t^2ab(b-1){t}^{b-2}-4tab{t}^{b-1}+6at^b = {t}^{\frac{7}{2}}\\
ab(b-1)t^b-4abt^b+6at^b = {t}^{\frac{7}{2}}\\
t^b(ab^2-ab-4ab+6a) = {t}^{\frac{7}{2}}\\
at^b(b^2-5b+6) = {t}^{\frac{7}{2}}\\
at^b(b-2)(b-3) = {t}^{\frac{7}{2}}\\
a{t}^{b-\frac{7}{2}}(b-2)(b-3) = 1
$$

For the equation to be true for every $t$, we should have:

$$
b-\frac{7}{2} = 0\\
a(b-2)(b-3) = 1
$$

We get:

$$
b=\frac{7}{2}\\
a(\frac{7}{2}-2)(\frac{7}{2}-3) = 1
$$

$$
b=\frac{7}{2}\\
a(\frac{3}{2})(\frac{1}{2}) = 1
$$

$$
b=\frac{7}{2}\\
a = \frac{4}{3}
$$

So our particular solution is:

$$
y(t) = \frac{4}{3} {t}^{\frac{7}{2}}
$$

Comment: my complementary equation is $y(t) = C_1(t^2) + C_2 (t^3)$

Comment: @marg_ocruz. Which is correct !